# Samba (CIFS) mount error(9): Bad file descriptor

Tags: linux, windows, samba, mount, cifs

I had successful connections from my main workstation PC (which uses Fedora 29 Workstation) to my mother's laptop (Windows 7 HP) network share few times using mount.cifs, but since not too long it has become impossible for me to do it.

For example, using Nautilus, connecting to smb://192.168.0.2/Data asks for a credentials (although it should be stored permanently for this share already), and even when you enter a correct username and password, it does nothing but just prompts for how to login again.

Using mount -t cifs was also successful in the past but not anymore, since it returns an error as following:

```
[ruslan@sakuya ~]$ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/Data .mount/samba -o username=ruslan,password=[mypassword],domain=WORKGROUP,iocharset=utf8,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
mount error(9): Bad file descriptor
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
[ruslan@sakuya ~]$ sudo mount -t cifs //PATCHOULI/Data .mount/samba -o username=ruslan,password=[mypassword],domain=WORKGROUP,iocharset=utf8,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
mount error(9): Bad file descriptor
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
[ruslan@sakuya ~]$ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/Data .mount/samba
Password for ruslan@//192.168.0.2/Data:  **********
mount error(9): Bad file descriptor
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
[ruslan@sakuya ~]$ sudo mount -t cifs //PATCHOULI/Data .mount/samba
Password for ruslan@//PATCHOULI/Data:  **********
mount error(9): Bad file descriptor
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

dmesg isn't also very helpful on its' side:

```
[ 4342.451104] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
[ 4342.455203] Status code returned 0xc0000008 STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE
[ 4342.455217] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -9
[ 4342.455237] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -9
```

Specifying the PC name and/or removing any or all of options does not help in any way.

Comment: Does this Windows 7 system had some updates recently? https://serverfault.com/q/948263/78437

Comment: Yes, I saw the system update icon in the tray but haven't digged any further. Thank you very much for a hint, I will read the discussion and delete those updates if it will be necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: someone from the community has noticed that official update fixing the problem has been released; [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/948263/kb-4480970-and-or-kb-4480960-breaks-smb2-connections-to-windows-7-shares/948831#948831) provides a solution:

> Microsoft released the Update [KB4487345](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4487345/update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2) to fix the issue:
>
> > This update resolves the issue where local users who are part of the local “Administrators“ group may not be able to remotely access shares on Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 machines after installing the January 8th, 2019 security updates. This does not affect domain accounts in the local "Administrators" group.
>
> So [download](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4487345) and install the update by doing a double click on the msu file.

Comment: As noted in https://serverfault.com/a/948831/268610 , there is now a better solution to both: install the official fix.

Comment: Thank you. Is is being installed automatically on every Windows 7 system or you need to download it manually?

Comment: After I installed the 2019-01 Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 (KB4480955) as part of the normal Windows Update, I no longer encounter this error. (KB4480955 doesn't seem to explicitly mention including the KB4487345 patch though.)