# Administrators lost access to network drive and remote desktop Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, administrative-privileges

Three days ago, all the users with administrator role could not connect to our server (Windows Server 2008 R2) via network drive or remote desktop, while general users could apply these functions as usual. The administrators can still log in at the server machine directly. The security setting of the drives and the setting of the remote desktop control are alright. The only thing altered that day was that there was a Windows update of MS SQL Server 2014.

What should I check? Many thanks in advance for any advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two recent Windows Updates (KB 4480970 and KB 4480960) broke the ability for administrators to access SMB2 shares on several OS versions, including Windows Server 2008 R2. That fits your description quite well.

See: [KB 4480970 and or KB 4480960 breaks SMB2 connections to Windows 7 shares](https://serverfault.com/questions/948263/kb-4480970-and-or-kb-4480960-breaks-smb2-connections-to-windows-7-shares) and https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/01/09/windows_7_network_broken/

Uninstall those updates, or install the fixed version from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4487345/update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2

Comment: Oh! Great! The problem is tackled. Thank you so much!